# Trying to understand what \s is matching

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
rule[param,argument]
```

but it can be just

```
rule
```

I am trying to get all words without the square brackets and the commas.

```
/([\w]+)(\[\s([a-zA-Z\d_]+,?)*\])?/
```

The regular expression works like a charm, but I can't figure it out why \s is needed in order to match separate words, not the string as whole.
As I know, the \s matches any space character such and it is equal to  `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, but I do not have any of these in the string of question.
Can you explain why `\s` is needed?

I am testing the code using php and javascript, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the above example, the match was done only by this `[\w]+` regex not by the pattern inside the second capturing group since you made the second group as 
**optional**.

You may check it by running  `([\w]+)(\[\s\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t([a-zA-Z\d_]+,?)*\])?` regex.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dA0uY5/1)

Answer (score 1):

The second part of regex is not responsible for the matches that you are getting.. they are matched by `([\w]+)`

Pattern for string inside `[ ]` is not getting matched because you inluded the `\s` which is not there in the string and you made the pattern optional by `?`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3vQ0/1)